# K-Means Algorithm Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am implementing K-Means Algorithm on Hadoop(Old API) and I am stuck at a point where I am not able to figure out how to proceed further.

My logic till now is:

Maintain two file centroids & data.

- **Step 1**: Read the centroids file & store this data in some `list(ArrayList)`.
- **Step 2**: Then read the data file through mapper as it will scan line by line then compare this value with already stored centroids in the list.
- **Step 3**: Output the corresponding centroid & data to reducer.
- **Step 4**: Reducer will process the new centroid and emit it with the data.

### My Questions

1. Is my flow correct?
2. Is it right way to store centroid file first in some collection and then proceed further?
3. If I go with approach (2) then my problem is that how to store this centroid file in some collection  because as map function will scan file line by line so how to scan this centroid file first before running the mapper on data file?
4. What should be a better way to handle this centroid file functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your flow looks almost alright to me.  You shouldn't be "reading" your data file, you should just be specifying that as your input to the hadoop program.  Besides that, while not always ideal MapReduce/Hadoop systems can do Iterative algorithms just fine. Just make sure you link the output of the reducer to the input of the mapper.
2. Yes it is correct, You can use either the distribute cache, or just store the file in the hdfs path.  Reading in the centroid file at the start of a mapper can be done inside of the "setup" method.

   ```
   public class MyMapper extends Mapper{
       @Override
       protected void setup(Context context){
           //setup code.  Read in centroid file
       }
   }
   ```
3. See my code above, use the "setup" method.
4. I think the centroid file is fine, that file is going to be trivial to pass around due to its very small size (unless you are trying to have millions of clusters...)

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought but as I am using old Api so is the functionality of "configure" method same as this of "setup" ?

Comment: Yes the MapReduceBase.configure(JobConf), is the old api version of Mapper.setup(Context)

Comment: @greybuddha: The distribute cache that we have in hadoop it will save the file only for one iteration right? and in the second iteration automatically the file will be deleted or I have to handle that?

Comment: So the Distributed cache uses a "absolutepath#filename", which resides on the hdfs.  So unless you are deleting the folder which contains the cache, it will persist.  As an example if you look at TeraSort, it places the DistributedCache file inside of the Output folder, which certainly is not deleted.

Comment: So I am not sure here..so let say in each iteration I am creating a new JobConf so as per your comment the file cached in the previous iteration will persist in the next iteration(or next new JobConf)? I think it will cache only for one Job configuration(one iteration of map and reduce) ..not sure though.

Comment: So it looks like you are right, the cache is set by the job and goes away when the job does. So the cache is only for that job, but the cache file is not deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop is not the best fit for K-means as you need to run several map-reduces to get the result. That said  Apache Mahout includes a [k-means implementation](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/k-means-clustering.html) for Hadoop and you can use it (or look at its implementation).

[Apache Hama](http://hama.apache.org/) which is a Bulk Synchronous Parallel processing framework on top of Hadoop is a better fit as it allows message passing between participating componets and it has k-means implementation [3]. It would be more common to see solutions like this on Hadoop 2 when [YARN](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html) will be out of beta

Comment: Yes Arnon...but I am looking more towards learning so I am trying to implement this to learn how actually k-means will work on MapReduce.

Comment: @Anon Hama has a kmeans version in trunk for ages, so no need to link to these old implementations.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut I remembered it did but couldn't find it in the morning (6am :) ) I edited the answer. JackSparrow - you can still look at the implementations and learn from them  (the code is open source)

Comment: Here it is: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hama/trunk/ml/src/main/java/org/apache/hama/ml/kmeans/KMeansBSP.java?view=markup

Comment: The link in the answer is dead.

Comment: That's because during the 2 years that passed  the Mahout project realized that iterative algs are better handled by platforms like Spark, Flink and changed course